# percentage per month Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working in Bigquery and I need the percentages for each result for each month, I have the following query but the percentage is calculated with respect to the total, I have tried to add a PARTITION BY in the OVER clause but it does not work.

```
SELECT CAST(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CAST((created_at) AS TIMESTAMP), MONTH) AS DATE) AS `month`,
  result,
     count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(1)) over() as percentage
FROM table_name

GROUP BY  1,2
ORDER BY  1
```

| month | result | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01 | 0001 | 50 |
| 2021-01 | 0000 | 50 |
| 2021-02 | 00001 | 33.33 |
| 2021-02 | 0000 | 33.33 |
| 2021-02 | 0002 | 33.33 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the data that you shared as:

```
WITH data as(
SELECT "2021-01-01" as created_at,"0001" as result UNION ALL
SELECT "2021-01-01","0000" UNION ALL
SELECT "2021-02-01","00001"UNION ALL
SELECT "2021-02-01","0000"UNION ALL
SELECT "2021-02-01","0002"
)
```

I used a subquery to help you to deal with the month field and then use that field to partition by and then group them by month, and result.

```
d as (SELECT  CAST(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CAST((created_at) AS TIMESTAMP), MONTH) AS DATE) AS month,
 result, created_at
 from DATA
 )
SELECT d.month,
 d.result,
    count(*) * 100.0 / sum(count(1)) over(partition by month) as percentage
FROM d
 
GROUP BY  1, 2
ORDER BY  1
```

The output is the following:

[image]

Comment: @franco pina I Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This example is code on dbFiddle SQL server, but according to the documentation google-bigquery has the function `COUNT( ~ ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ~ )`

> ```
> create table table_name(month char(7), result int)
> insert into table_name values
> ('2021-01',50),
> ('2021-01',30),
> ('2021-01',20),
> ('2021-02',70),
> ('2021-02',80);
> ```

> ```
> select 
>   month, 
>   result, 
>   sum(result) over (partition by month) month_total, 
>   100 * result / sum(result) over (partition by month) per_cent
> from table_name
> order by month, result;
> ```

> ```
> month   | result | month_total | per_cent
> :------ | -----: | ----------: | -------:
> 2021-01 |     20 |         100 |       20
> 2021-01 |     30 |         100 |       30
> 2021-01 |     50 |         100 |       50
> 2021-02 |     70 |         150 |       46
> 2021-02 |     80 |         150 |       53
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=45d835711d1f1e1e904b12bfc3b06dbf)*